# Python XML parser doesn't get all text

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have following XML source.

```
<a>
  <b>
     first
  </b>
  second
</a>
```

I try to parse it with python to get the text out and combine the whole text to one string like `firstsecond`. For this I have the following script

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

top = ET.fromstring(myXml)
for a in top.iter('a'):
  s = ''
  if a.text:
    s += a.text
  else:
    for b in a.iter('b'):
      if b.text:
        s += b.text
  print s
```

But the script just prints the first element `first`. The second somehow seems to get lost. It works when I have both strings in `<a></a>` or both in `<b></b>`.

```
<a>
  firstsecond
</a>
```

Prints `firstsecond`

```
<a>
  <b>
     first
  </b>
  <b>
     second
  </b>
</a>
```

Prints `firstsecond`

Am I missing something to get out the second string when its in the same `<a></a>` as the `<b></b>`? Or is this just not possible with etree and I have to repack it? The XML is given, I won't be able to change the source therefore.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to simplify it with the `tostring` function.

```
top = ET.fromstring(myXml)
for a in top.iter('a'):
  s = ET.tostring(a, method='text')
  print s
```

This function just combines all the texts of the elements and subelements

Answer (score 3):

`b.tail` will contain `second` in your first example. Text after an end tag is considered `tail` in ElementTree. Actually it will contain the whitespace as well and be more like `\n  second\n`.

Consider a nicely formatted data block of XML:

```
<a>
  <b>first</b>
  <b>second</b>
</a>
```

Here you will get data fields in `b.text` and whitespace formatting in `tail`, which can easily be ignored.

Comment: thanks, that works. But I just found the tostring function to make it easier, then I don't depend on whether it is before or after the child element.

Comment: @Memnon Yes, that is a helper function that collects all the text and tail. But most XML documents look like my nicely formatted example above, where you don't want the tail, which is why the concept exists.

Comment: I'd absolutely prefer a nicely formatted XML, but that's how I get it. I was thinking also about reformatting it before parsing but that's annoying as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one, I tested it on your xml file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
x = 'xml.xml' # your xml file
tree = ET.parse(x)
root = tree.getroot()
string = ""
for c in root:
 string +=  c.text.strip()
print string
```

output:

```
 firstsecond
```